# Inserting into DB from data in Hash and Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have defined my hash and arrays like this:

```
POPULATION_SUMMARIES = {
    'ACO' => [   # year , member_count
        [2013, 523031],
        [2012, 492349],
        [2011, 432573]
    ]
}
```

So the table I want to insert into is **PopulationSummary** . And its row/fields are like this:

```
    ACO, 2013, 523031
    ACO, 2012, 492349
    ACO, 2011, 432573
Org_id, year, member_count
```

In DB, It's actually the ID of those "ACO" or other stuff, they are basically foreign keys of another table.(ie. Organization table).

So I am trying to loop through this and read the structure and write it in the table. 
I went as far as something like this:

```
  POPULATION_SUMMARIES.each do |k, v|
    org_id = Organization.find_by_name(k).id  # so for example ID of ACO
    v.each do |o| # now read elements of each array
      # HERE :(  QUESTION
    end
  end
```

So the part I am having trouble with is how to say Ok the first number you read from the array, insert it for the year field, the second number you read from the table: insert it for member_count field....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close:

```
POPULATION_SUMMARIES.each do |org_name, summaries|
  org = Organization.find_or_create_by_name(org_name)

  summaries.each do |year, member_count|
    PopulationSummary.create({
      :organization => org,
      :year         => year,
      :member_count => member_count
    })
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm? what is the third line in your code?  "year, member_count = values"  Does it work like that?

Comment: Yes, this will assign the first and second value of the array on the right side to the variables on the left side. you could as well write `year = values[0]` and `member_count = values[1]`, it's just syntax sugar

Comment: Note that `find_or_create_by_name` will create an `Organization` object if there is none with the given name, so you will always be able to set the relationship.

Comment: Sorry, the code that i wrote before would only insert one `PopulationSummary` per `Organization`, but i have fixed it (see updated post)

Comment: Maybe you need parentheses around the hash, again see my edit